# Locate original repository of each dependency in maven

Tags: maven, repository, dependency-management

Scenario:
New enterprise policy forbids from using public repositories. For every dependency used (which are a lot) we have to provide to the devOps team the artifact group, id, version and from which repository it came.

We have used more than one external repository on our code base. Since all the artifacts are now on the local repository, we don't know where they came from.

What I was able to do:

I can use 
mvn dependency:list -DoutputAbsoluteArtifactFilename=true -DprependGroupId
on each project to get artifact group, id, version.

And mvn dependency:list-repositories to get the repositories used in that project

What's missing:

Knowing which artifact is from which repository.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid this will not be possible in maven. Prior to maven 3.0.x, maven did not even kept track of remote repositories. After Maven 3.0.x, it moved to eclipse aether. Eclipse aether create _remote.repositories file for every repository which has repository information. It contains repository id which is defined in your settings.xml file. You could,

1. Delete your local repo contents.
2. Run following command,

   ```
   find . -name _remote.repositories -exec grep "^[^#;]" {} \; > repo_info.txt
   ```

This will atleast give you the mapping.

Comment: **Great answer**. Thank you. I ended up determining repos by hand, according to the group id of each dependency (like 700, it took some time >_<). If dev ops gets annoying I will go with this.

Answer (score 0):

Make a list of all external repositories that you use. Furthermore, take the list of all groupId, artifactId, version (Either by `dependency:list` each project or by scanning the local repository). Now for each dependency, ask the external repositories via REST if they contain this dependency.

If you start with MavenCentral, you have a high chance that you find your dependency in the first try.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will definitely go with this route if devOps have a problem with just a couple of the dependencies. Do you know how to make the REST query? I have curl and wget, but any other tool will do too.